# Unable to start profiler in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling

After launching the performance wizard, selecting Instrumentation, choosing one web project and a few C# library projects, and enabling Tier Interaction Profiling, I get this weird leading off with:

> Restoring the configuration file failed. File '`...\web.config.backup.3b2912c9-3849-2724-8317-1a7da3819869`' could not be copied to '`...web.config`'. The process cannot access the file '`...\web.config`' because it is being used by another process.

I should also add that the web application in question is hosted in IIS. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you opened your web.config in another editor?

Comment: Yes, I've verified the file isn't locked in any way.

Comment: Weird permissions on the file maybe? Allow full access to everyone temporarily to check?

Comment: I read some posts about similar problem; can be an antivirus blocking control? Tried clean/build your project? Can you check who is using web.config with "Process Explorer" (SysInternals)? Can this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121386/unable-to-copy-file-reference-dll-to-bin-reference-dll-the-process-cannot-acces?

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I have the same problem and non of the answers below is a solution for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Had the same. what I did is to find who's holding my files (did it using the ["process explorer"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from SysInternal). you need to use the "Find Handle Or DLL" - shortcut CTRL+F and put the address and it will find the relevant processes.

The handle that hold my file was the process "Windows Event Collector Service" so I killed it and all came back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar with web.configs. You say it's hosted using IIS, is the web.config actually in the wwwroot (or sub directory of that)?

And I guess you are using Windows 7/Server 2008?

Its UAC if so.

You can turn of User Account Control, or run whatever application it is as administrator, even if you 'are the administrator'.

Or just copy [do not move!] the files to your 'my documents', do whatever with them, then put them back.

Either way, I would try the upgrade with a copy of the files in your 'my documents' folder to ensure you have all the privileges you need.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while working with VS2012, but discovered it was AppFabric on my local development machine that was holding the web.config hostage.

I disabled and stopped the Services on my local box and everything was back to normal.